# Accessing functions from subdirectories in python, where to place __init__.py file?

Tags: python

I have the following directory/file layout for some code in python.

```
- top_directory

  -fileA.py
  - sub_directory 
    - __init__.py (do i place it here?)
    - sub_sub_directory 
      -fileB.py    (testFunc inside this file)
```

From inside the `fileA.py` i would like to access a function called `testFunc` inside `fileB.py`. I read a couple other question that talk about how to do it if its one subdirectory deep but this is two. Which subdirectory should i place the **init**.py file in? And what should the import statement look like of the file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Answer (score 1):

You can just put your fileB.py where indicated and import it with

```
import sub_directory.sub_directory.fileB as fileB
```